# Print division 3 in a row(left to right)

Tags: php, mysql

The following code results display left to right. While taking the print its coming down one by one. To take the printouts of address. How can I get the print from left to right 3 in a row?

```
<section class="contact-page-section">
      <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
    <?php

                $query = "SELECT * FROM sub";

                $num_results_per_page = 4;
                $num_page_links_per_page = 5;

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
pagination($query, $num_results_per_page, $num_page_links_per_page, $pg_param);

if($pg_error == '')
{
if(mysql_num_rows($pg_result) > 0)
    {
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($pg_result))
        {
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-3 col-sm-6\">
                        <div class=\"shop-item-small bg-alfa\">
                            <h6>". $data['id_user'] .".&nbsp;". $data['firstname'] .".&nbsp;". $data['lastname'] ."</h6>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\">". $data['address'] ."<br/>". $data['district'] ."&nbsp;-&nbsp;". $data['pincode'] ."<br/>". $data['state'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". $data['country'] ."</p>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\"><b>Phone : </b>". $data['phone'] ."</br>
                            <b>Mobile : </b>". $data['mobile'] ."</br>
                            <b>Email : </b>". $data['email'] ."</p>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\"><b>From : </b>". $data['subfrm'] ."</br>
                            <b>To : </b>". $data['subto'] ."</br>
                            <b>C/O : </b>". $data['co'] ."</p>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\"><b>". $data['through'] ."</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;". $data['amount'] ."</br>
                            <b>Details : </b>". $data['bankdetails'] ."</p>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\"><b>OrderForm No : </b>". $data['orderform'] ."</p>
                            <p class=\"sub-title\"><b>Agent : </b>". $data['agent'] ."</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>";
        }


echo "<div class=\"errormsg\">$pagination_output</div>"; 
}
else
{
echo "<p>No subscriptions to display</p>";
}
}
else{
echo $pg_error; //display any errors, you can remove this if you want}?>
```

Please help me to sort out this.